# Why do I get a different number in the inspector than the actual value?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I was trying to rotate the directionLight of the skybox using a simple script. However, I had a weird glitch where I wanted to make it so that if the directionLight was above a certain degree, it would shut off. In the inspector, it said that the rotation was well above that degree, but when I used print to see what the value of the rotation was, it gave me a different value for the rotation than the one in the inspector. So, I saw something like 200 in the inspector but only like 0.7 when I typed in print (object.transform.rotation.x)

Why are the two different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `transform.rotation` is a `Quaternion`. its' x doesn't have to be the x-axis. You want to print the euler angles:

```
rotation.eulerAngles.x
```